# Install existing win98 hdd in win7 computer

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive

I want to take the hard drive from my win98 and install it into a win7 computer (remove the existing hard drive in the win7).
I use win98 to run dos programs that I created years ago and I want to continue to use them.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem with this is that you will have hard time finding drivers for Windows 98 and on top of that if it's computer that's running Windows 7 it likely has no drivers at all available for Windows 98 and because of that this will not work at all.

Now what you can try is that you can try to install the harddrive into the computer as secondary harddrive and then run Windows 98 through a virtual machine. Now I haven't tried this myself so I can't really give a good advice on that, but apparently VMWare works well enough with this sort of thing and from what I've read VirtualBox cannot or couldn't handle existing operating system very well, or at least it wasn't easy to get to work.

Comment: Second problem is that the modern PC might be *too fast* for some DOS applications/games to run properly. Also, forget about trying to use USB in DOS.